# Killing people in the future vs sending them back in time

Tags: looper

Considering how the mob in the future went into such trouble to dispose of "unwanted" individuals, sending them to the past,

> how come they just simply kill Joe's wife, by shooting her in the belly, instead of just simply sending her back in time to have a Looper kill her in the past?

Wouldn't there be serious repercussions to their actions? If not, doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of sending people back through time?

Comment: The whole premise is ridiculous. To kill with a time machine, teleport the victim into space (or the Antarctic). Neither guns nor executioners are necessary.

Comment: I was under the impression we had an unreliable narrator who was lied to about why he did what he did. The point was actually to arbitrage silver over time and something about the time machine tech only worked on people. The folks were likely random abductees.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This wasn't fully explained in the movie, but the director and writer of the film has [explained this in interviews](http://www.slashfilm.com/ten-mysteries-in-looper-explained-by-director-rian-johnson/).  In the future, everyone has some nanites implanted.  When a person dies, these nanites broadcast to the authorities the location of the dead person.  So, anyone who is murdered is instantly on the police's radar.  The time machine works around this by having them just vanish as far as the future is concerned.  In the past, the police aren't setup to receive the nanites' broadcasts, so their murder is unreported there as well.

> “Everybody in the movie has this nano technology tracking in their
>   body and whenever there’s a death, a location tag is sent to the
>   authorities from this tracking material. So they can’t kill people in
>   the future. But if they send them back, that is not triggered.” He
>   continues, “The material is powered off the body’s heat and it has a
>   two year life after the person dies.” As for the wife, that was a big
>   mistake made by the mobsters and the reason we see the shot of the
>   village burning is that’s their half-assed attempt to cover it up.

In this particular instance, an incompetent group of mob henchmen accidentally killed Joe's wife.  This meant they knew the authorities would be there soon, so they needed a way to cover it up.  They set the house on fire, which you can see as they're leaving future Joe's house.  Thus the henchmen hope the death will be blamed on the fire.

This doesn't explain why the mob allows henchmen to run around with lethal weapons.  Presumably, they'd all be outfitted with those futuristic tazers that we saw them use on Joe.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just shoot Joe as well instead of bothering to send him back in time? They were going to burn the house down anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, they were sending people in the past because in the future it was not possible to dispose of someone **without leaving any evidence**. So this was a method most likely done for high-profile individuals, who were killed without leaving a body or any remains.

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1276104/faq#.2.1.1), it seems that the death of Joe's wife was a mistake, not something done because they knew they can get away with it:

> This was a big blunder made by the henchman, hence why they have set fire to the house in an attempt to cover their tracks. They were only meant to take Old Joe but the henchman was startled by his wife and fired carelessly.

Here's a quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looper_%28film%29):

> Tracking technology has rendered it nearly impossible to dispose of
>   bodies secretly, so crime bosses use illicit time travel to send those
>   they want killed to the past where they are killed by "loopers":
>   assassins paid with silver bars strapped to the victim.

Comment: Er...  Can't they just be tracked to the time machine, then?

Comment: Ok, so they track them back where the time machine was used to send them back in the past. Then what? Any signal tracked is no longer there and the time machine can be hidden or moved

Comment: It seems logical, however, I would assume Police would connect his wife to him after they find her dead and him gone.